# Modal is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal window using jQuery with id.

**My code:**

```
function PopUpWindow(popup) {
    var remote = "<iframe width='100%' height='90%' style='border:none; ' src='" + popup + "' ></iframe>";  // popup// $jq191(this).data('href');

    //alert($('#modalC .modal-body').html() );
    e = 'click';
    $('#modalC .modal-body').html(remote);
    $('#modalC').modal('show');

    // alert($('#modalC .modal-body').html());
    //alert('Hi         ');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

window.closeModal = function () {
    $('#modalC').modal('hide');
};
```

This code is ok before  `$('#modalC').modal('show');` but not after that.

Comment: please create a jsfillde or plunker

Comment: Most likely it's failing on the `e.preventDefault()` line. `e` should be an Event object, not a string. I'm also assuming you're referring to jQuery and Bootstrap modal dialogs, since they are not specified.

Comment: `e` is not declared...its probably giving an undefined error

Comment: I  am new in javascript .please tell me where to declare e ?

Comment: see error in browser console (press F12)

Comment: <a data-toggle='modal' id="AnchorLogin" runat="server"  href="javascript:void(0)"  style="padding-left:10px;"  onclick="javascript:PopUpWindow('/Myprofile/login.aspx');">Login</a>

Comment: why use `runat="server"` ? do you also need any server side functionality on this?

Comment: I was just trying  to call the click event of anchor link                           e = 'click'; and then   e.preventDefault();